# helm configmap in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am trying to do the following, so where MYVALUE in host needs to change to include Release Name. Can't figure how to do this, as you can't use env variables like `{{ .Release.Name }}` directly in to a values.yaml file.

I did do a `fullnameOverride` and put `fullnameOverride: myrelease-mysql` for the mysql pod and then jasper has `host: myrelease-mysql` that works  but wanted to know if there was a clever way to put release name into a values.yaml file.

I assumed I would need to use a configMap as can use `.Release.Name` there and then embed that config key into values.yaml.

**Values.yaml**

```
jasperreports:
  mariadb:
    enabled: false
  externalDatabase:
    host: MYVALUE   // Also tried $MVALUE
    user: sqluser
    database: jasper
  jasperreportsUsername: jasper
  env:
      - name: MYVALUE
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
              name: mysql-jasper
              key: mysql_releasename
```

**ConfigMap**

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-jasper
data:
  mysql_releasename: {{ .Release.Name }}-"mysql"
```

Comment: How is `.Values.jasperreports.externalDatabase` used?  I'd probably fill in this value when I'm creating the ConfigMap with the application configuration.  It's tricky to put Helm template code into the `values.yaml` file (the chart needs to be specifically aware of it) and you can't read back from a ConfigMap into Helm values.

Comment: So its set in values file only as used for connectivity to mySQL database, I’m using bitnamis chart: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/jasperreports/#installing-the-chart

Comment: Hi @sam, any progress?

Comment: No, I just used the fullnameoverride for the pod name without the release name, couldn’t figure out how to embed env variables into the values file to keep the release name/tag. Don’t think its possible.

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to to read variable from the ConfigMap (in your case it is `mysql-jasper` ConfigMap) in the `values.yaml` and set the value of the `MYVALUE`, and then use the `MYVALUE` to set value of the `jasperreports.externalDatabase.host` variable?

Comment: Correct, wasn't sure if this was possible. At present, I have used a fullnameOverride so that the pod name is the host of the externalDatabase, weren't sure if I can retain the release name without doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems that helm does not support any template rendering capabilities in  a `values.yaml` file - there are multiple topics on the helm GitHub:

- [Canonical way of using dynamic object names within values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/9754)
- [Adding values templates in order to customize values with go-template, for the chart and its dependencies](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/6876)
- [Proposal: Allow templating in values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2492)

For now this feature is not implemented so you need to find a workaround - the suggestion from David Maze seems to be a good direction, but if you want to follow your approach you can use below workaround [using `--set` flag in the `helm install` command](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/#helm-install) or use `sed` command and pipe to `helm install` command.

First solution with `--set` flag.

My `values.yaml` file is little bit different than yours:

```yaml
mariadb:
  enabled: false
externalDatabase:
  user: sqluser
  database: jasper
jasperreportsUsername: jasper
```

That's because when I was using your `values.yaml` I couldn't manage to apply these values to `bitnami/jasperreports` chart, the `helm install` command was using default values [from here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/jasperreports/values.yaml).

I'm setting a shell variable `RELEASE_NAME` which I will use both for setting chart name and `externalDatabase.host` value.

```
RELEASE_NAME=my-test-release
helm install $RELEASE_NAME bitnami/jasperreports -f values.yaml --set externalDatabase.host=$RELEASE_NAME-mysql
```

The above `helm install` command will override default values both by setting values from the `values.yaml` file + setting `externalDatabase.host` value.

Before applying you can check if this solution works as expected by using `helm template` command:

```
RELEASE_NAME=my-test-release
helm template $RELEASE_NAME bitnami/jasperreports -f values.yaml --set externalDatabase.host=$RELEASE_NAME-mysql
...
- name: MARIADB_HOST
  value: "my-test-release-mariadb"
...
```

Another approach is to set a bash variable `RELEASE_NAME` which will be used in the `sed` command to output modified `values.yaml` file (I'm not editing `values.yaml` file itself).  This output will be pipe into a `helm install` command (where I also used the`RELEASE_NAME` variable).

`values.yaml`:

```yaml
mariadb:
  enabled: false
externalDatabase:
  host: MYHOST
  user: sqluser
  database: jasper
jasperreportsUsername: jasper
```

```
RELEASE_NAME=my-test-release
sed "s/MYHOST/$RELEASE_NAME-mysql/g" values.yaml | helm install $RELEASE_NAME bitnami/jasperreports -f -
```

This approach will set chart configuration the same as in the first approach.